# Insert & alter table SQLite-Eclipse-Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

i need your help to improve my android application.

First - I have three tables (Contacts, Products and Order), when is adding a new Product registration i need to get it's name and with that info add a new Order column, to do that just know i need an alter table but i don't know where put it.

This is where the tables creates..

**// NOTE: PEDIDOS = ORDER ... SORRY !!**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BDDatos";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
// Products table name
private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
 // Products table name
private static final String TABLE_PEDIDOS = "pedidos";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private final ArrayList<Contact> contact_list = new ArrayList<Contact>();

// Products Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_PROD_ID = "prod_id";
private static final String KEY_PROD_NAME = "prod_name";
private static final String KEY_DESC = "desc";
private static final String KEY_PRES = "presio";
private final ArrayList<Product> product_list = new ArrayList<Product>();

// Request Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_PEDIDO_ID = "pedido_id";
private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_ID = "product_id";
//private static final String KEY_CANTIDAD = "cantidad";
private final ArrayList<Pedido> pedido_list = new ArrayList<Pedido>();


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT" + ")";

db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);   

String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "("
    + KEY_PROD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_PROD_NAME + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_DESC + " TEXT," + KEY_PRES + " TEXT" + ")";

db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);

String CREATE_PEDIDOS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PEDIDOS + "("
        + KEY_PEDIDO_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_PRODUCT_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES PRODUCTS(KEY_PROD_ID)"+ ")";



db.execSQL(CREATE_PEDIDOS_TABLE);

}



// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// Drop older table if existed
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PEDIDOS);

// Create tables again
onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
public void Add_Contact(Contact contact) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone
values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail()); // Contact Email
// Inserting Row
db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Adding new product
public void Add_Product(Product product) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues prod_values = new ContentValues();
prod_values.put(KEY_PROD_NAME, product.get_prodName()); 
prod_values.put(KEY_DESC, product.get_prodDesc()); 
prod_values.put(KEY_PRES, product.get_prodPresio()); 
// Inserting Row
db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, prod_values);
db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

/*public void OnUpgrade_table(SQLiteDatabase db){

    ContentValues prod_values = new ContentValues();
    final String columna_producto = product.get_prodName();
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE" + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "ADD COLUMN" + columna_producto + "STRING");

}*/

// Adding new pedido
public void Add_Pedido(Pedido pedido) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues pedido_values = new ContentValues();
pedido_values.put(KEY_PRODUCT_ID, pedido.get_contact_id()); // Contact Name
//pedido_values.put(KEY_CANTIDAD, pedido.get_prodDesc()); // Contact Phone
// Inserting Row
db.insert(TABLE_PEDIDOS, null, pedido_values);
db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact Get_Contact(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
    KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO, KEY_EMAIL }, KEY_ID + "=?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
// return contact
cursor.close();
db.close();

return contact;
}

// Getting single product
Product Get_Product(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor prod_cursor = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, new String[] { KEY_PROD_ID,
    KEY_PROD_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_PRES }, KEY_PROD_ID + "=?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (prod_cursor != null)
    prod_cursor.moveToFirst();

Product product = new Product(Integer.parseInt(prod_cursor.getString(0)),
        prod_cursor.getString(1), prod_cursor.getString(2), prod_cursor.getString(3));
// return contact
prod_cursor.close();
db.close();

return product;
}

// Getting single pedido
Pedido Get_Pedido(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PEDIDOS, new String[] { KEY_PEDIDO_ID,
    KEY_PROD_ID }, KEY_PEDIDO_ID + "=?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Pedido pedido = new Pedido(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
    cursor.getString(1));
// return request
cursor.close();
db.close();

return pedido;
}


// Getting All Contacts
public ArrayList<Contact> Get_Contacts() {
try {
    contact_list.clear();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
        contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
        // Adding contact to list
        contact_list.add(contact);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return contact_list;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
}

return contact_list;
}

// Getting All Products
public ArrayList<Product> Get_Products() {
try {
    product_list.clear();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery1 = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor prod_cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (prod_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.set_prodID(Integer.parseInt(prod_cursor.getString(0)));
        product.set_prodName(prod_cursor.getString(1));
        product.set_prodDesc(prod_cursor.getString(2));
        product.set_prodPresio(prod_cursor.getString(3));
        // Adding contact to list
        product_list.add(product);
    } while (prod_cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    prod_cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return product_list;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.e("all_product", "" + e);
}

return product_list;
}

// Getting All Pedidos
public ArrayList<Pedido> Get_Pedido() {
try {
    pedido_list.clear();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery2 = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PEDIDOS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor pedido_cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery2, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (pedido_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
        pedido.set_pedidoID(Integer.parseInt(pedido_cursor.getString(0)));
        pedido.set_prod_id(pedido_cursor.getString(1));
        //pedido.set_reqCant(pedido_cursor.getString(2));
        // Adding contact to list
        pedido_list.add(pedido);
    } while (pedido_cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return request list
    pedido_cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return pedido_list;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.e("all_request", "" + e);
}

return pedido_list;
}

// Updating single contact
public int Update_Contact(Contact contact) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());
values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());


// updating row
return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Updating single product
public int Update_Product(Product product) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues prods = new ContentValues();
prods.put(KEY_PROD_NAME, product.get_prodName());
prods.put(KEY_DESC, product.get_prodDesc());
prods.put(KEY_PRES, product.get_prodPresio());


// updating row
return db.update(TABLE_PRODUCTS, prods, KEY_PROD_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(product.get_prodID()) });
 }

// Deleting single contact
public void Delete_Contact(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
db.close();
}

// Deleting single product
public void Delete_Product(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_PRODUCTS, KEY_PROD_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
db.close();
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int Get_Total_Contacts() {
String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
cursor.close();
// return count
return cursor.getCount();
}

// Getting products Count
public int Get_Total_Products() {
String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
cursor.close();

// return count
return cursor.getCount();
}

// Getting pedido Count
public int Get_Total_Pedido() {
String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PEDIDOS;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
cursor.close();

// return count
return cursor.getCount();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onUpdate` method is there to help You update a database schema in new version of app.

In Your code I see You taking common approach of deleting all tables and calling `onCreate`.

So You have to adjust `CREATE TABLE...` queries in `onCreate` and increase value of DATABASE_VERSION constant.